# ng-repeat within directive will not update when adding or modifying objects to the existing collection

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-directive, angularjs-digest

I've got a treeview which contains objects with nested arrays that I am trying to populate.

[A working plunker may be found here.](http://plnkr.co/edit/drC46ZOqWviM0PVVVzy4?p=preview)

Here is a breakdown of how the code is structured and what I have tried thus far.

Within my treeview.html view I am loading the treeview directive I have created:
I currently have two just to test the bindings. The second one will not populate until the incident checkbox has been checked.

```
<H3>Tree View Sameple</H3>

<div>
  <h3>Treeview 1</h3>
    <tree src="tree.treeData" iobj="object" filter="tree.getAggregateInfo(object, isSelected)"></tree>
    <h3>Treeview 2 once object has been updated</h3>
    <tree src="tree.treeData2" iobj="object" filter="tree.getAggregateInfo(object, isSelected)"></tree>
</div>
<hr/>
<p>javascript object data</p>
{{tree.treeData}}
```

The bottom binding is just showing the output of the js file. Wihtin the treeview when you click on the incident checkbox I am simulating a new nested collection being retrieved that should be inserted as a child element under the incident node of the tree.

Here is the code used in the treeviewController.js

```
(function () {

    angular.module('app')
           .controller('treeviewController', ['$log', '$scope', '$timeout', treeviewController]);
    function treeviewController($log, $scope, $timeout) {

        var vm = this;
       //storage container for last node selected in tree
        vm.lastNodeSelected = '';

        vm.treeData2 = {};//test container to reflect object once updated
        //original data not an arry but an object holding an array
        vm.treeData = 
            {
                "children": [
                  {
                      "name": "Document Type",
                      "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "Incident",
                            "documentType": "Document Type",
                            "aggregateUponField": "_ocommon.documenttype",
                            "parent": "",
                            "count": 2950,
                            "children": null
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Some Event",
                            "documentType": "Document Type",
                            "aggregateUponField": "_ocommon.documenttype",
                            "parent": "",
                            "count": 2736,
                            "children": [{
                                        "name": "Some Event Date",
                                        "children": [
                                                    {
                                                    "name": "2008",
                                                    "documentType": "Incident Date",
                                                    "aggregateUponField": "dateincidentstart",
                                                    "parent": "",
                                                    "count": 451,
                                                    "children": null
                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                    "name": "2009",
                                                    "documentType": "Incident Date",
                                                    "aggregateUponField": "dateincidentstart",
                                                    "parent": "",
                                                    "count": 407,
                                                   "children": null
                                                   },
                                                   {
                                                   "name": "2010",
                                                   "documentType": "Incident Date",
                                                   "aggregateUponField": "dateincidentstart",
                                                   "parent": "",
                                                   "count": 426,
                                                   "children": null
                                                   }
                                                  ]
                                       }]
                        }
                      ]
                  }
                ]
            };

        //aggregate data to be nested under incident
        vm.newChildData = [
              {
                  "name": "Incident Date",
                  "children": [
                    {
                        "name": "2008",
                        "documentType": "Incident Date",
                        "aggregateUponField": "dateincidentstart",
                        "parent": "",
                        "count": 451,
                        "children": null
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "2009",
                        "documentType": "Incident Date",
                        "aggregateUponField": "dateincidentstart",
                        "parent": "",
                        "count": 407,
                        "children": null
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "2010",
                        "documentType": "Incident Date",
                        "aggregateUponField": "dateincidentstart",
                        "parent": "",
                        "count": 426,
                        "children": null
                    }
                  ]
              } 

        ];


        var loadData = function () {
            //stip out array
            var children = vm.treeData.children;
            //search array for matching parent
            $log.info(vm.lastNodeSelected);
            var cnt = children.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
                if (children[i].children) {
                    var innerCnt = children[i].children.length;
                    for (var c = 0; c < innerCnt; c++) {
                        if (children[i].children[c].name === vm.lastNodeSelected) {
                            children[i].children[c].children = vm.newChildData;

                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            //wrap back in object and assign to ngModel
            vm.updatedList = { children };
            // $log.info(updatedList);      

            vm.treeData2 = vm.updatedList;
            $timeout(function() {
                $scope.$apply(function() {
                    vm.treeData = vm.updatedList;
                })} , 0);
        }

        vm.getAggregateInfo = function (node) {

            vm.lastNodeSelected = node.name;
            loadData();
           // $log.info(vm.lastNodeSelected);
        };


    }

})();
```

Following is the treeview directive.

```
angular.module('app')
    .directive('tree', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            scope: {
                t: '=src',
                filter: '&'
            },
            template: '<ul><branch ng-repeat="c in t.children track by $index"  src="c" filter="filter({ object: object, isSelected: isSelected })"></branch></ul>'

        };
    });

angular.module('app')
.directive('branch', function ($compile) {

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            b: '=src',
            filter: '&',
            checked: '=ngModel'
        },

        template: '<li class="dir-tree"><input type="checkbox" ng-click="innerCall()" ng-model="b.$$hashKey" ng-change="stateChanged(b.$$hashKey)"  />{{ b.name }}  <span ng-hide="visible"> ({{ b.count }})</span></li>',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            var clicked = '';
            var hasChildren = angular.isArray(scope.b.children);
            scope.visible = hasChildren;
            if (hasChildren) {
                element.append('<tree src="b" filter="filter({ object: object, isSelected: isSelected })"></tree>');
                $compile(element.contents())(scope);
            }
            element.on('click', function (event) {
                event.stopPropagation();
                if (hasChildren) {
                    element.toggleClass('collapsed');
                }
            });
            scope.stateChanged = function (b) {
                clicked = b;
            };

            scope.innerCall = function () {
                scope.filter({ object: scope.b, isSelected: clicked });
            };
        }
    };
});
```

What I am seeing is when I click on the incident check box the javascript object does update. You can see this in the output as well as the second treeview that gets bound once the check box is selected.

I suspect the issue is related to the $digest cycle of the event and the tree is not being notified to actually update. I've tried as you can see in the controller using a `$scope.$apply()` wrapped in a timeout but this has not worked to update the original tree.

Doing additive actions like a `.push()` to the array updates however trying to insert a new object into an existing array does not seem to work.

Any suggestions on how to get the tree to update and reflect the child objects?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to populate treeview1, then treeview2. In that order? If so, I would use a promise to load treeview1, then load treeview2 inside the controller. Then your directives will "load" in that order too

Comment: Treeview 2 is just there for testing. it represents the correct data structure of the object once the nested objects are added. The expected output would be once the new collection is added to the original list. Treeview 1 would update showing the nested items (in this instance the dates under incident)

Comment: I can't see any use of promises in your code. It smells like promise-food. Are you familiar with $q?

Comment: I don't think a promise has anything to do with this scenario.  I've normally used promises in scenarios of working with services, and handling on success/error, or chaining functions together. Here I am updating an existing item/adding to the array. I think the issue is a $watch is needed on the directive. However if you have a possible solution where a promise is used I'd love to see it. thanks

Comment: I read your question too fast. "The second one will not load until...". I thought that was your problem :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a slightly modified [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/XgJgFcwGlPQAqy06g8kZ?p=preview) to highlight (and partially fix) the problem.

I added the following lines to the `link` function in the `branch`directive:

```
scope.$watch('b', function (newvalue, oldvalue) {
    if (!oldvalue.children && newvalue.children) {
        scope.visible = true;
        element.append('<tree src="b" filter="filter({ object: object, isSelected: isSelected })"></tree>');
        $compile(element.contents())(scope);
     }
}, true);
```

The `link`function is not called again, when the tree structure gets updated. Thus, if there are new children to be added, those will not get compiled for Angular.